# Queries in mysql 5.7 2 or more times slower than in 5.1

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We migrated a full database from MySQL 5.1.63 to a different (a bit better) server into MySQL 5.7.22. Now most of the queries are 2 times slower on average. We haven't done too much optimization for MySQL 5.1.

Here is the configuration which we have changed:

```
table_open_cache            = 4096
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
query_cache_limit       = 1000000
query_cache_size        = 32000000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3200M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 1024M
```

Here is one concrete example:

I want to get all the persons who are marked as a teacher in a course:

```
SELECT id, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(" ", name, lastname)) AS name
FROM person
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id FROM course)
ORDER BY name;
```

The run time:

- mysql 5.1: 0.03s. subsequent queries: 0.00s
- mysql 5.7: 1.27s. subsequent queries: 0.80s

The difference is 40+ times.

EXPLAIN in 5.1:

```
+----+--------------------+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | type           | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | person   | ALL            | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL | 16293 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | course   | index_subquery | teacher_id         | teacher_id         | 5       | func |  2677 | Using index; Using where    |
+----+--------------------+----------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN in 5.7:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref                  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | person      | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY            | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |  16491 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2> | NULL       | eq_ref | <auto_key>         | <auto_key>         | 5       | db.person.id         |      1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | course      | NULL       | index  | teacher_id         | teacher_id         | 5       | NULL                 | 109741 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Now if I write the query like that:

```
select distinct person.id, trim(concat_ws(" ", name, lastname)) as name 
from person, course
where person.id = course.teacher_id
order by name;
```

Times will become:

- mysql 5.1: 0.01s
- mysql 5.7: 0.03s

So, it's a bit better, but still slower.

`course.teacher_id` has an index.

One of the differences between the installations is that in the server with 5.7, data folder is on another drive (SSD, the performance is a bit better than for the drive in 5.1 server).

Any suggestions what should I configure to get 5.7 to the same speed as 5.1? Probably some of the queries have to be rewritten too, but I think configuration seems necessary.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 has a better optimizer and optimize queries different vs MySQL 5.1... Oh and drop the old comma join syntax `from person, course` which is over 25 years old use proper `table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column` syntax..

Comment: "The run time:

    mysql 5.1: 0.03s. subsequent queries: 0.00s
    mysql 5.7: 1.27s. subsequent queries: 0.80s
" i have a feeling the Query Cache kicks in on the MySQL 5.1 server... Besides you should not be using Query Cache annyway. The Query Cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: How much RAM?..

Comment: Which table are `name` and `lastname` in?  Which `name` do you want the `ORDER BY` to use?

Comment: Please use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` when timing.  This avoids the QC.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! 
@RaymondNijland First, using join vs table1, table2, the join was 2-3 times slower. That's why I tried "the old" way. Also, if no cache, should I do anything special about that?
@RickJames 4MB RAM. `name`  and `lastname` are in `person` table. Will update my question with `SQL_NO_CACHE`

Comment: Also a query profile ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html ) would tell you also more where the time is spend..  query profiling was available in MySQL 5.1 found some old documentation http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profile.html (not official MySQL website)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the better query otimization  using  an inner join

```
  SELECT id, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(" ", name, lastname)) AS name
  FROM person
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id FROM course
  ) t on  t.teacher_id = person.id 

  ORDER BY name;
```

and be sure that you test are do in the same condition  ..  same data  .. and first execution for both query

Comment: No, second execution, but with QC turned off.  The first may involve priming the buffer_pool; the second is better because it avoids that.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty cool and I get 0.00 time with that query. The problem is, I have a system which has hundreds of queries (some join together 20 tables). I would prefer (at least as a temporary solution) some way to use the same queries with about the same time as in 5.1.

Comment: As in the comment to your question by @RaymondNijland  the QC is changed .. and the if you need  better performance you should eval a refactoring for the slowest queries ..as in my answer .. explecially where you use a IN clause  based  on a subquery .. these should be changed  using an inner join

Comment: As I see I can change the queries, my problem is that there are too many of those. My initial goal would be to get 5.7 working as fast as 5.1 (without changing queries in the first place).