# MySQL server execute query took long time

Tags: mysql, wampserver

### **Why MySQL server took time compare than MySQL inside wamp ?**

Machine 1 installed MySQL 5.6.17(inside the wamp)

Machine 2 installed MySQL 5.7.24(separate server)

Both machines are same configuration and same OS.

I imported same DB dump file to Machine1 and Machine2.

Now I execute query (the query get data from 6 join tables) and return 400 rows.

**Took time:**

Machine 1 (5.6.17) inside wamp- Below 30 sec's

Machine 2 (5.7.24) - Morethan 230 sec's

Shall I use MySQL(wamp) instead of MySQL server?

Comment: You need to add the query itself and the execution plans for both servers (write `explain ` directly infront of your query, e.g. `explain select ... ` and add the output to your question). Depending on that, we can tell you where to look next. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51328384) to get an idea how your question could look like/should contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MySQL server need to increase **Innodb_bufferpool_size** on my.ini which located from C;\Program Data (Default hidden folder)

Default Innodb_bufferpool_size is 8M

innodb_buffer_pool_size: This is a very important setting to look immediate after the installation using InnoDB. The InnoDB is the buffer pool where the data is indexed the cached, which has a very large possible size that will make sure and use the memory no the disk space for most of the read-write operations, generally the size of InnoDB values are 5-6GB for 8GB RAM.

Fix: Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size

> innodb_buffer_pool_size=356M